# How to close the container <div> from the inner page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, html, iframe

I have the following structure :

My page opened in a frame like this :

```
<div id="ajaxbox" class="dhtmlwindow" style="z-index: 101; width: 73%; visibility: visible; display: block;">
<div class="drag-handle" style="opacity: 1;">
Title
<div class="drag-controls">
</div>
<div class="drag-contentarea" style="height: 715px; overflow: hidden; display: block;">
<iframe name="_iframe-ajaxbox" style="margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height: 100%" src="">
//My Page opened here
</iframe>
....
```

---

Now i wanna from a `linkbutton` in my page to close the container (`div id="ajaxbox"`)

How to do this ?

Comment: Why is the div not already closed by whoever started to write it?

Comment: hmmm , i wanna in the `linkbutton click` and after some action to close this div automatically

Answer (score 1):

Write a javascript function that closes the div in your parent page.

jQuery example:

```
function CloseDiv()
{
    $("#ajaxbox").hide();
}
```

in on your link button call a client script:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="LinkButton1"
       text="Close Me"
       onclientclick="parent.CloseDiv()"
       runat="Server" />
```

Comment: hmmm, thanks but it doesn't work. i wanna to close the parent container in the child page not the parent !!

Comment: What is the id of the parent container? Why can't you just hide it?

Comment: the `id` as the question above from `firebug`

Comment: yeah but there is an `iframe` in then the page contents

Comment: If you hide the div, the iframe in it, and the page contents in that frame would be hidden too.

Comment: hmmm, i put the `jquery` on my child page then call the function on the client click like your instruction but nothing happened

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15836/discussion-between-nunespascal-and-just-name)